# Bypassing closed or filtered ports

Tags: ssh, server, ports

I recently setup a basic Ubuntu Server at my home and while at school can't access it because the SSH port (22) has been closed. This lead me open up different ports on my server for SSH so that I could access via an open port at my school. I ended up opening port 21 typically for FTP because I did a network scan and found it was open on the school network. I tested SSH from my home network onto the server using port 21 and was successful but upon attempting it at school I was unsuccessful. My question is why was it unsuccessful? And what can be done to fix it?

I am aware that I shouldn't be trying to circumvent there blocks but I am really curious on why it isn't working.

Comment: Could be they are doing Deep Packet Inspection and dropping anything that looks like ssh - they can do a lot more than just look at ports and addresses if they want to

Comment: Maybe but why would they? Also this is a public school that doesn't have unlimited resources for security.

Comment: Generally to shut down Command and Control connections back from malware to their controlling server.  They may well be running a standardized firewall with a standardized set of rules created by people who decently know what they are doing at the board or ministry level (if a public school)

Comment: Alright well thank you for your help. What would you recommend? Would a VPN work or is SSH access just not an option.

Comment: You could try a vpn, but I suspect it'd be similar results.  There are some that conceal traffic over https, which can't be packet inspected, but you're starting to get into 'willfully bypassing security', which is likely grounds for unpleasant action.  I'd let it go if I were you

Comment: What does the packet capture say? Always, always, always capture packets to diagnose network problems.

Comment: They could simply be blocking outgoing traffic on port 21...

Comment: What would I be looking for in the packet capture? I have done a scan to confirm port 21 is open.    
You are right and I am of course not trying to do anything wrong. I just would like to be able to work on my project whenever I've got time.

Comment: You'd be looking for what's happening to the packets. Are they being dropped or are you getting a response from something? How far are the packets getting? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yo're assuming the problem is at the school, but you may be wrong; the problem may be at your ISP or your router. Have you done a portscan on your public IP address using an online portscanner? Does it report port 21 at your public IP as open?

It sounds like you set up a server at home. So to reach it from school, you must pass the schools firewall, the ISPs firewall and the firewall installed on your home router. Outgoing firewalls are usually configured to allow traffic to common services such as ftp, so while possible, its unlikely that your school would deny an outgoing ftp connection.

Incoming connection attempts are a different story. ISPs often configure their firewalls to block common ports to protect their clients' home networks from attacks. The same goes for your home router.

Even if port 21 on your public IP address is accessible from the internet, to reach your server, you must configure your router to forward connections to port 21 to the server machine. If you don't do that, you try to reach your router's ftp port, which will be closed or filtered.

Your server is reachable from home because it sits in the same network, so there are no firewalls to pass through which could block traffic.